# How to use 2 adapters in 1 recycleview?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android application in which I get information from an Api.

here's a drawing of what i have in mind.

[Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80yQi.png)

Comment: You should use one adapter and multiple view types for this case.

Answer (score 0):

1 adapter can do the job. What you need is multiple view holders in a single adapter. Create view holders by extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

Example:

```kotlin
class ExampleAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val context = parent.context
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_VIEW_HOLDER_ONE -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_one, parent, false)
                ViewHolderOne(view)
            }
            else -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.view_holder_two, parent, false)
                ViewHolderTwo(view)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        // Logic to return which view is which type
    }

    internal class ViewHolderOne(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    internal class ViewHolderTwo(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Comment: but where should i call the methods these doubts suggest ?

Comment: I have added an example